# как очистить v-model в дочернем компоненте из родительского?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Пожалуйста, помогите мне. Я пытаюсь 10 часов подряд, но ничего не получается. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии в @click="cleanDataForm" в родительском компоненте => text v-модел в дочернем компоненте был "" . И я попробовал сделать это с помощью props, computed, vuex- и ничего. Я буду очень признателен, если вы поможете .

//Родительский

```
<template>
    <div class="Main">
        <div class="comment">
            <Smiles
            />
            <div class="btns">
                <button id="btn--send" type="submit" @click="sendData">Send data</button>
                <button id="btn--clear" @click="cleanDataForm">clean data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

//Дочерний

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <textarea
            v-model="text"                          !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1
            ref="smilesTextarea"
            placeholder="Введите комментарий"
        ></textarea>
        <button @click="showSimiles"></button>
    </div>
</template>
```

И мне нужно this.text="", когда я нажал отправить данные в родительском. Сказали как-то можно через refs,но не знаю как. Буду очень признателен если поможете.

Comment: Если вы используете vue3 + подход composition api = vuex вам нахрен не нужен) P.S. читал только заголовок вопроса :)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите очищать text из родительского компонента, то он должен быть частью data родительского компонента и передаваться в дочерний через props.

Родительский:

```
<script>
...
data(){
  return {text: ''}
},
methods: {
  cleanDataForm(){
    this.text = '';
  }
  sendData() {
    ...
    this.cleanDataForm();
  }
}
...
</script>
<template>
    <div class="Main">
        <div class="comment">
            <Smiles
              v-bind:text="text"
            />
            <div class="btns">
                <button id="btn--send" type="submit" @click="sendData">Send data</button>
                <button id="btn--clear" @click="cleanDataForm">clean data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Дочерний:

```
...
  props: ['text'],
```